# How to centre a div vertically and horizontallly?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I want to position at the center of a page(both vertically and horizontally).

For centring it horizontally I used the **center** tags around the div and for vertically centring it is tried a couple of things but none of them actually working.

Check out the code:

CSS:

```
.vcenter{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: calc(50% - 25px);
}
```

HTML :

```
<center>
    <div class="vcenter">

    </div>
<center>
```

Also I don't think using centre tags around the the div to centre an object is the best way to so it.

What I want to know is

- How can I centre the div both vertically and horizontally no matter what the size of the screen is ?
- Is there a better way to centre the div horizontally rather than using the **center** tags ?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#hv3

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ for a flowchart style guide. Both links are good for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If available, using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) is the easiest. Apply these styles to the container in which you want to center your `div`:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: please use flex. The sooner we all start using it the sooner all browser will decently support it. And it makes the live of a developer so much easier! And this is a great cheat sheet if you want to use the basics: http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html

Comment: Just added a link to the answer. Personally, I've found this reference to be very helpful: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: What does "If available " implies to ?

Comment: Browser support is limited (this is a newer feature) so it depends on your target audience.

Comment: So like do i need to use an alternative as well, if yes, how shall I work that out

Comment: @Rasik depends on your target browsers. A good alternative is @JohnSpecko's answer, although not sure why he suggests `position: fixed` as opposed to `position: absolute`

Comment: Pretty cool, but unfortunately can't use it on my current stuff due to users that are still on older versions of IE.

Comment: @SkinnyJ Just a copy paste from my source code and I'm using fixed for a processing notification.

Answer (score 3):

```
#divId {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The only thing that isn't obvious is the transform takes into account the size of the element.

Comment: @SkinnyJ edited to answer your question. Thanks for noticing.