# vertical and horizontal centering - responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am vertically and horizontally center a div with the following markup/css:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
}
.content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        centered content
    </div>
</div>
```

My content looks fine when the browser is wide enough. However, I would like to somehow define a smaller width the content should stay within when resizing the width of the browser. I have text I don't want running into the right and left edge of the browser when it gets small enough, so I'd like to wrap it onto more lines. What is the best way to handle this responsively?

Comment: Show us your relevant HTML + CSS (that's not enough to help you at the moment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to centre a div vertically and horizontallly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703851/how-to-centre-a-div-vertically-and-horizontallly)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your wrapper a width and set margin to auto

[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Horizontal_centering_with_margin_0_auto)

```
.wrapper{ width:50%;  margin:0 auto; }
```